# Swift conversion issue

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Converting some of my code from Objective-C to Swift. Got stuck in a combination of typecasting statement:

```
if (![[array objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[BaseView class]]) {
    //Throw an exception
}
```

Since the branching should throw an exception, I am using guard statement instead of if-else. So far I have done the following:

```
guard NSArray(array: array).objectAtIndex(0) else {
    //throw SomeException
}
```

Please guide the remaining part, how to use the `isKindOfClass`, also I doubt the correctness of `NSArray` typecasting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The more correct method is to use `is`, as its meant to replace `isKindOfClass`.

```
guard array.first is BaseView else {
    // Throw exception if its not a BaseView subclass
}
```

Comment: That is definitely the clearer way if you do not want to get hold of actual first object but only check that is of some kind +1.

Answer (score 3):

The following works in your case:

```
guard let arr0 = array.first as? BaseView else {
    return // or throw exception
}
```

You *try* to cast the value in `array.first` to `BaseView` and if that conversion fails you will enter the `else` block and can throw an exception if you wish. Additionally (thanks to @Adam) that will return/throw if the array is empty. If you have to check for the 3rd element to be of a certain type, you should check that the array actually contains at least 3 values.

Consider the following example:

```
func t(arr : [AnyObject]) {
    guard let arr0 = arr.first as? String else {
        return
    }
    print(arr0)
}

t(["asd", 123]) // prints something
t([123, "asd"]) // returns without printing anything
t([])           // returns without printing anything
```

Comment: I would use `array.first` instead of `array[0]` to avoid "index out of range" error in case when the array is empty.